# How to pressed a UIButton within a customized TableviewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I have been looking all throughout SO on how to interact with a UIButton within a customized tableview cell. All of the answers I have seen are using IBOutlets, however I have not seen a way to do this fully programmatically. I am use to interacting with buttons via button.addTarget. Here are my two ViewControllers, one being the customized tableviewcell and the other being the ViewController.

Here is my customized. I tried using a protocol delegate route, however this has failed.

```
import UIKit


@objc protocol TableViewNew {
    func onClickCell()
}


class NewMoveTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
     var cellDelegate: TableViewNew?
    
    
    
   
    static let identifier = "NewTableViewCell"
    
    private let myImageView: UIImageView = {
       let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = .purple
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 80/2
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private let myLabel : UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "test"
        label.backgroundColor = .blue
        label.textColor = .systemPink
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.textAlignment = .center
        
        return label
    }()
    
    private let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Invite", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return button
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(myImageView)
        addSubview(myLabel)
        addSubview(button)
        setImageConstratins()
        setTitleLabelConstraints()
        setButton()
       
        

    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setImageConstratins() {
        
        myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        myImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        myImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    func setTitleLabelConstraints() {
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        //myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    func setButton() {
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    }
    
    public func configure(with name: String, label: String) {
        myLabel.text = label
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: name)
    }
    
  
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        myLabel.text = nil
        myImageView.image = nil
    }
    
    
    @objc func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        cellDelegate?.onClickCell()
    }
  
    
    
}
```

Secondly, here is the ViewController that the TableView is within.

```
import UIKit

class NewMoveViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
       let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
     
        
        
        
        return tableView
    }()
    
    
    
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    

    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        collectionView?.register(NewMoveCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NewMoveCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false 
     
        title = "Add to Group"
        tableView.register(NewMoveTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NewMoveTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.delegate = self

        
        guard let myCollection = collectionView else {
            return
        }
        
        view.addSubview(myCollection)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        
    }
    
    
}

extension NewMoveViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NewMoveTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! NewMoveTableViewCell
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        cell.configure(with: "", label: "test")
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
  
    
    
}


extension NewMoveViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NewMoveCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! NewMoveCollectionViewCell
        
    
        return cell
    }
    
   
    
    
}


extension NewMoveViewController : TableViewNew {
    func onClickCell() {
        print("Pressed")
    }
```

I conformed this ViewController to the protocol from the customized cell and put the function within the cell's cellForRowAt function. When I use this route, I run my app and everything comes up fine, however when I try to click on the customized tableviewcell within the viewcontroller, nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every time you say `addSubview(myImageView)` etc., that is _wrong_. Never add a subview directly to a cell. Add it to the `contentView`. Otherwise, the subview will be behind the content view and you won't be able to tap your button.

Comment: Also, as Dexter points out, you forgot to call `addTarget`. You say "I am use to interacting with buttons via button.addTarget" but you never do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the action handler to your button:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```